# How to make callback function using jQuery Boilerplate

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, callback

I'm creating a new jQuery plugin using [jQuery Boilerplate](http://jqueryboilerplate.com/) patterns. Can you help me showing the best way to create a callback function?

```
// the semi-colon before function invocation is a safety net against concatenated 
// scripts and/or other plugins which may not be closed properly.
;(function ( $, window, undefined ) {

  // undefined is used here as the undefined global variable in ECMAScript 3 is
  // mutable (ie. it can be changed by someone else). undefined isn't really being
  // passed in so we can ensure the value of it is truly undefined. In ES5, undefined
  // can no longer be modified.

  // window and document are passed through as local variables rather than globals
  // as this (slightly) quickens the resolution process and can be more efficiently
  // minified (especially when both are regularly referenced in your plugin).

  // Create the defaults once
  var pluginName = 'defaultPluginName',
      document = window.document,
      defaults = {
        propertyName: "value"
      };

  // The actual plugin constructor
  function Plugin( element, options ) {
    this.element = element;

    // jQuery has an extend method which merges the contents of two or 
    // more objects, storing the result in the first object. The first object
    // is generally empty as we don't want to alter the default options for
    // future instances of the plugin
    this.options = $.extend( {}, defaults, options) ;

    this._defaults = defaults;
    this._name = pluginName;

    this.init();
  }

  Plugin.prototype.init = function () {
    // Place initialization logic here
    // You already have access to the DOM element and the options via the instance, 
    // e.g., this.element and this.options
  };

  // A really lightweight plugin wrapper around the constructor, 
  // preventing against multiple instantiations
  $.fn[pluginName] = function ( options ) {
    return this.each(function () {
      if (!$.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName)) {
        $.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName, new Plugin( this, options ));
      }
    });
  }

}(jQuery, window));
```

Comment: It's not very clear what you mean by _callback function_...Can you elaborate?

Comment: Ie.: In init() I have x and y. I need to return these values ​​using a callback function.

Comment: Then just return the values, instantiate the object with `data` and call the method you want on it.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't understand what you mean by *callback* in this situation. If what you want is to have a method that returns values you have to create an instance of the object with `data` and then you can call the method you want.

```
var $instance = $('selector').plugin( options ).data('plugin_pluginName');
var returnedValue = $instance.methodThatReturnsSomething();
```